# data from views.py to Django forms

Tags: python, django, forms

I am a newbie in Django and I have learn some basic things about it. My problem is, I get data from django models but I am not able to pass/display it to a form. I would like to have a forms.py with 1 phone_id Selector and 3 textInputs in order to insert data to the desired phone.

My models.py:

```
class Phone(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    num_calls = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    time_btwn_calls = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    psap = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
```

My forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class phoneForm(forms.Form):

    NumberOfCalls = forms.CharField(
        min_length = 1,
        widget=forms.TextInput({'class': 'form-control'})
        )

    TimeBetweenCalls = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput({'class': 'form-control'})
        )

    PSAP = forms.CharField(
        min_length = 1,
        widget=forms.TextInput({'class': 'form-control'})
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        phone_choices = kwargs.pop('phone_choices')
        super(Send2tcu, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['phone'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            required = True,
            widget = forms.Select({'class': 'form-control'}),
            choices = phone_choices
        )
```

I just create a form with the 3 textInputs and the MultipleChoiceField where I need to display the data from the differents phone_id.

My view.py:

```
def phone_config(request):
    phones = Phone.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id).values_list('id', flat=True)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = phoneForm(request.POST, phone_choices=phones)
        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
            phone_id = cleaned_data.get('phone')
            NumberOfCalls = cleaned_data.get('NumberOfCalls')
            TimeBetweenCalls = cleaned_data.get('TimeBetweenCalls')
            PSAP = cleaned_data.get('PSAP')
            Tcu.objects.filter(id=phone_id).update(
                num_calls = NumberOfCalls,
                time_btwn_calls = TimeBetweenCalls,
                psap = PSAP,
            )
            return redirect(reverse('gracias'))
    else:
        form = phoneForm(phone_choices=phones)
    return render(request, 'configurer/configurer.html', {'form': form})


def gracias_view(request):
    return render(request, 'configurer/gracias.html')
```

In my view first of all, I get the all the phone_id for the current user. Then I check if the method is post and I get the data from the form and also I pass to the form the different phone_ids.Then I check if the form is valid and I create the object Phone. After that assign the different parameters to the selected phone_id and save them.

There is something wrong in my code. I am getting this error:

> TypeError at /configurer/
>
> 'int' object is not iterable
>
> return render(request, 'heroconfigurer/heroconfigurer.html', {'form':
>   form})

Comment: Could you include the stack trace? (You may also want to read about `ModelForm`s at some point)

Comment: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.5-py2.7.egg\django\forms\widgets.py in render_options , line 539

Answer (score 0):

models.py:

```
class Phone(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        num_calls = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
        time_btwn_calls = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
        psap = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py:

```
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput, Select

class PhoneViewForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        widgets = {'user': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                  'num_calls': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                  'time_btwn_calls': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), 
                  'psap': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
                  }
        fields = ['user', 
                  'num_calls', 
                  'time_btwn_calls', 
                  'psap'
                  ]
```

If you manipulate model objects in your form Django recommends you to use ModelForm. You also may fill this form with initial model instance. Hope that helps.